# Pylint errors on vs code

Tags: python

I am having trouble with **pylint**. When I run my code it gives me a **pylint** error on all the files where I have imported a function from django:

> Unable to import 'django.http'pylint(import-error).

And yet I have installed **pylint** on vs code and it shows that **pylint** has been enabled.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Welcome to our homepage")
```

Please assist

Comment: Did you install ``pylint`` *only* on vs code? Do you have maybe another installation of ``pylint`` for a python interpreter that does not have ``django`` installed?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve same issue by:

0. installing pylint-venv by

```
   pip install --user pylint-venv
```

1. generating pylint config file using next command

```
    pylint --generate-rcfile > ~/.pylintrc
```

2. uncommenting and editing the init-hook line in aforementioned file so in my case it looks like this

> init-hook="import sys; sys.path.append("/home/coldnegative/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages"); import pylint_venv; pylint_venv.inithook(force_venv_activation=True)"

where **/home/coldnegative/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages** is my user path to python libs installed with **pip**

3. setting pylintArgs in VS Code **settings.json** to

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--rcfile", "${env:HOME}/.pylintrc"
],
```

P.S. It is also advisable to use **pylint-django** plugin install it with pip and using by editing the load-plugins line in pylint config file

> load-plugins=pylint-django